FilamentPHP V3: Loging in from Admin panel redirects to another panels login route
I have two panels in a FilamentPHP V3 project. By default the Admin and Student panel. I have also added a new authGuard for the Student panel.
The issue is that when I log in from the admin panels login route, it redirects me to the student login route which should not happen. Interestingly, when I am logged in to both panels, the redirection works perfectly afterward.
Note: after login when directly visiting the route /admin, it takes me to the correct admin dashboard.
My question is how can I solve this problem?

Both of your panels are set as default, probably. Check your panel providers! For me removing one solved the issue.

This seems nothing to do with it. The second panel is not set to default
